# JS: Load localstorage in other page

Tags: javascript, arrays

I need to load an array from localstorage.

I'm adding form inputs into an array to the localstorage like this:

```
document.querySelector("#addMeal").addEventListener("click", newMeal);
function newMeal(e){
e.preventDefault();

let title = document.querySelector("#title").value;
let img = document.querySelector("#img").value;
let book = document.querySelector("#book").value;
let calories = document.querySelector("#calories").value;
let servings = document.querySelector("#servings").value;
let type = document.querySelector("#type").value;
let price = document.querySelector("#price").value;
let cook = document.querySelector("#cook").value;
let quantity = document.querySelector("#quantity").value;

let newMeal={
    id: 23,
    title: title,
    img: img,
    book: book,
    calories: calories,
    servings: servings,
    type: type,
    price: price,
    cook: cook,
    quantity: quantity};
meals.push(newMeal);
console.log(meals);

// Put the object into storage
localStorage.setItem('meals', JSON.stringify(meals));}
```

Now I need to load that array into an other page.
I already have this part of code but this isn't working.
Doen anyone know what i'm doing wrong?

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', loadMeals);

function loadMeals() {
let retrievedObject = localStorage.getItem('meals');
console.log(meals);
let i = 0;
let id = 1;
let fillMealList = document.querySelector("#fillMealList");
for (let i = 0; i < meals.length; i++) {
    let item = meals.find(item => item.id === id);
    fillMealList.innerHTML +=
        "<article class='objectP'>"+
        "<h3>" + item.title + "</h3>"+
        "<figure>"+
        "<img src='images/" + item.img + "'" +">" +
        "<figcaption>"+
        "Meal by: " +"<span>" + item.cook + "</span>" +
        "</figcaption>" +
        "</figure>"+
        "<div class='info'>"+
        "<p>€ <span>" + item.price + "</span>" + "/pp" + "</p>" +
        "<a href='javascript:addToCart(" + item.id + ")' class='addToCart'>Order</a>"+
        "</div>"+
        "</article>";
    id++;
}}
```

Comment: try `let retrievedObject = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('meals'));` to convert your string back into an array of objects

Comment: do you see any error in console related to this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have 4 mistakes as I can see.

First, you need to parse the string that you received from your local storage.

```
let retrievedObject = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('meals'));
```

Second, that `console.log(meals);` will probably throw an error because I can't see `meals` in that scope.

Third, the line that you put meals to localStorage has a wrong semicolon. It will throw an error. Try putting semicolon to end of the line.

```
localStorage.setItem('meals', JSON.stringify(meals));
```

Fourth and probably the main problem that you have similar to your second problem. If `meals` is not defined as an array, you can't use its prototype method `push`, it will throw an error. Add `const meals = []`.

Answer (score 2):

```
 document.querySelector("#addMeal").addEventListener("click", newMeal);
function newMeal(e){
e.preventDefault();

let title = document.querySelector("#title").value;
let img = document.querySelector("#img").value;
let book = document.querySelector("#book").value;
let calories = document.querySelector("#calories").value;
let servings = document.querySelector("#servings").value;
let type = document.querySelector("#type").value;
let price = document.querySelector("#price").value;
let cook = document.querySelector("#cook").value;
let quantity = document.querySelector("#quantity").value;

let newMeal={
id: 23,
title: title,
img: img,
book: book,
calories: calories,
servings: servings,
type: type,
price: price,
cook: cook,
quantity: quantity};
meals.push(newMeal);
console.log(meals);
localStorage.setItem('meals', JSON.stringify(meals));}
```

after doing  this open the file you may want to access and initialize a variable

```
let a =  localStaorage.getItem('meals)
let b =  JSON.parse(a);
console.log(b);
```

Answer (score 2):

Some errors were already pointed out [see working Snippet](https://jsfiddle.net/olayenca/hog67m2s/5/)

I have used JQuery and number inputs in this case.

```js
this.Run = function() {
  var meals = [];
  return {

    newMeal: function() {

      var title = document.querySelector("#title").value;
      var img = document.querySelector("#img").value;
      var book = document.querySelector("#book").value;
      var calories = document.querySelector("#calories").value;
      var servings = document.querySelector("#servings").value;
      var type = document.querySelector("#type").value;
      var price = document.querySelector("#price").value;
      var cook = document.querySelector("#cook").value;
      var quantity = document.querySelector("#quantity").value;

      var newMealData = {
        id: 23,
        title: title,
        img: img,
        book: book,
        calories: calories,
        servings: servings,
        type: type,
        price: price,
        cook: cook,
        quantity: quantity
      };


      meals.push(newMealData);

      // Put the object into storage
      localStorage.setItem('meals', JSON.stringify(meals));
    },

    loadMeal: function() {

      var retrievedObject = localStorage.getItem('meals');
      var i = 0;
      var id = 23;
      var fillMealList = $("#fillMealList");
      for (i = 0; i < meals.length; i++) {
        var items = meals.find(item => item.id === id);

        fillMealList.append(
          "<article class='objectP'>" +
          "<h3>" + items.title + "</h3>" +
          "<figure>" +
          "<img src='images/" + items.img + "'" + ">" +
          "<figcaption>" +
          "Meal by: " + "<span>" + items.cook + "</span>" +
          "</figcaption>" +
          "</figure>" +
          "<div class='info'>" +
          "<p>€ <span>" + items.price + "</span>" + "/pp" + "</p>" +
          "<a href='javascript:addToCart(" + items.id + ")' class='addToCart'>Order</a>" +
          "</div>" +
          "</article>");
        id++;
      }

    }

  };
}();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <div>
    <label for="title">Title</label>
    <input type="number" id="title">
  </div>

  <div>
    <label for="img">img</label>
    <input type="number" id="img">
  </div>
  <div>
    <label for="book">book</label>
    <input type="number" id="book">
  </div>
  <div>
    <label for="calories">calories</label>
    <input type="number" id="calories">
  </div>
  <div>
    <label for="servings">servings</label>
    <input type="number" id="servings">
  </div>
  <div>
    <label for="type">type</label>
    <input type="number" id="type">
  </div>
  <div>
    <label for="price">price</label>
    <input type="number" id="price">
  </div>
  <div>
    <label for="cook">cook</label>
    <input type="number" id="cook">
  </div>
  <div>
    <label for="quantity">quantity</label>
    <input type="number" id="quantity">
  </div>
</div>
<button id="addMeal" onclick="window.Run.newMeal()">Set Meal</button>
<button id="load" onclick="window.Run.loadMeal()">Load Meal Found</button>
<div id="fillMealList" style="border: 1px solid black; height: 200px; width: 100%;"></div>
```